# Need a real time experience

Tags: selenium-webdriver

** Need any real time script to view the architecture of any project **

Hey, I am working as a manual tester, I want to learn automation like selenium.

I can start learning and its completed to, But now I know the frameworks too.

But I don't know the exact flow how to design script for any real time project, How I get the real-time experiences.

Can you please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a question, do you work as manuel tester and do you want to keep earning while your work is being done for you? Or are you working as a tester who has to make these automated flows but just can't do it?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

[Basic tutorials are what you need](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-tutorial/), not just some real tests done as you won't learn.

In addition to that, I'd suggest you also to learn Jenkins, as it is REALLY usefull for automated tests in server.

And one more thing, before learning all of that, you should start learning by the different kind of tests there are (black box, white box, unitary, BDD). Getting right to your point, shorting all the learning, won't do any good.